# 960.gs grid, grid overflow

Tags: css, 960.gs

could someone please take a look at this and help me understand what i need to do to get the headings to sit inline with grid, as shown.

Its become div intensive because ive tried so many different ways to get the tabs to sit correctly. i understand that i probably dont need this many div's but i just cant see the wood for the trees at the moment...

http://www.virtualharrogate.co.uk/tabs

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With a `container_16` or `container_12` you have a max width of 960px. Your grids are 6 and they are all set as `grid_2`. That is 6x140px = 1000px, more than your global wrapper.

You have to choose having less `grid_2` or the same number but as `grid_1`.